# how to make query to get attachment image url in wp

Tags: php, wordpress

i was using database to get id=1 for example - location = image url

it was like that

```
include 'config.php';
$GetPicId = $_GET["pid"]; // Picture ID from Index page
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fbcover WHERE id=$GetPicId") or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_fetch_array($query);

$PicLocation =$result['location'];
```

now i would like to using wordpress

iam trying to get attachment image url by using post id for example

```
include 'config.php';
$GetPicId = $_GET["pid"]; // Picture ID from Index page
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id=$GetPicId") or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_fetch_array($query);

$PicLocation =$result['guid'];
```

and i always get this msg " failed creating formpost data "

how can i get attachment image url in

```
$PicLocation =$result['location'];
```

i really need help ... thanks

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` by default will only fetch the first record. You probably need to loop through the result set. `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
query_posts('showposts=3&post_type=image&orderby=rand');
global $more; $more=0;?>

<?php if (have_posts) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); global $more; $more=0;?>

<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_parent' => $post->ID );
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                echo '';
                // count number of available images and change if less than the specified limit
                foreach ($attachments as $post) {
                        setup_postdata($post);
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->ID, 'thumbnail', false );
                        echo '<span class="media"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" style="background-image: url('.$image[0].');">'.get_the_title().'</a></span>';;
                }
                echo '';
            }
            ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Courtesy: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-query-for-attachments

Answer (score 0):

If you using Wordpress then you should use build in function for it. If you have attachment id use [wp_get_attachment_url($att_id)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) to get link or
 [wp_get_attachment_image_src($att_id)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) to get path to file.

Here you have good examples of using `get_posts` to achieve what you want:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

### Show all attachments

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_parent' => null ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false ); //for url
            $path = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'your-size'); //for direct path to image
    }
}
```

### Show attachments specific post

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post_id ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false ); //for url
            $path = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'your-size'); //for direct path to image
    }
}
```

---

P.S.
If you want to create batch script or something out of site but with access to all WordPress "magic" add this at beginning:

```
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    require_once(BASE_PATH.'wp-load.php');
}
```

...and you will have access to all functions I mention above. Lookout on paths to wp-load.php file.